# Are f-strings a unique feature to python (3.6 and higher)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, language-concepts, f-string

With an f-string you can fill in 'placeholders' in a string directly with some variable value. Opposed to, let's say using the str.format() method, often seen.

Example:

```
In [1]: x=3
In [2]: y=4
In [3]: print(f'The product of {x} and {y} is {x*y}.')
The product of 3 and 4 is 12.
```

Is this concept of f-strings only found in python? Or is there any other language that supports this, maybe under a different name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No - not unique to python. In python it was introduced with 3.6 by [Literal String Interpolation - PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/?)

In C# there is [$ - string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) as shorthand for some function you would use [String.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.String.Format?view=netframework-4.7.2) for:

```
string val = "similar";
string s = $"This is {val}"     // s == "This is similar"

// vs. 

var s2 = string.Format ("This is {0}", val); // {0} = 0th param that follows
```

Comment: Note that C# interpolated strings are not always a shortcut for string.Format, if they can they just use string.Concat

Answer (score 1):

You can find it under the name of [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in Javascript as well. In particular, see the section Expression Interpolation for an example similar as the one in OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

**The shell:** Starting in the Dark Ages shells used to expand parameters in double quoted strings (and unquoted arguments too).

**Perl:** Perl has a shellish side, and had *interpolation* in double quoted strings from at least the time I bought the 1st edition of the Camel book and started learning the language.

I think that other people may be more specific on the precise date of introduction of string interpolation in Perl, but I suspect it was there from the beginning.

Many other programming languages, especially those using [sigils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)), share this concept of interpolation.